# continuity of function and subspace on topology

Tags: general-topology

Take topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ and a continuous function $f : X \to Y $.

Prove:

1) If $Z$ is a subspace of $Y$ containing the image $f(X)$ of $f$, then the function
$g : X \to Z$ defined by $g(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in X$ is continuous.

Things I know:

$Z$ is a subspace of $Y$, it means that $Z \subseteq Y$ and $ł_Z=\{Z \cap U : U \in ł_Y \}$ is a topology. $Z \cap U$ is open in $ Y$

Attempt of prove:

Take $U$ open in $Z$. $g^{-1}(U)=\{x \in X: g(x) \in U \}=\{x \in X: f(x) \in U\} = X \cap f^{-1}(U) $. By continuity $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, so $g^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$ and it implicates that $g(x)$ is continuous.

It make sense? How use the fact that $Z$ contains the image $f(X)$ of function $f$? Also I am not sure how to use definition of subspace.

Comment: It's just needed for $g$ to actually be a function $X\to Z$. It's a set theoretic necessity, but its topological content is null.

Comment: If $Z$ doesn't contain $f(X)$ then the definition of $g$ doesn't make sense...

Comment: The problem is: $U$ is not necessarily open in $Y$, so you can't conclude directly that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.  Hint: if $U$ is open in $Z$, use the definition of the subspace topology to get $V$ open in $Y$ such that $U = Z \cap V$; and then show $g^{-1}(U) = f^{-1}(V)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your approach:

As $f[X] \subseteq Z$ we know that for all $U \subseteq Y$ $$g^{-1}[U \cap Z]  = f^{-1}[U]$$

**Prooflet:** If $x \in g^{-1}[U \cap Z]$ then $g(x) \in U$, but as $g(x) = f(x)$, $x \in f^{-1}[U]$. On the other hand if $x \in f^{-1}[U]$ then $f(x) = g(x) \in U$ and also $g(x) = f(x) \in f[X] \subseteq Z$ so that $x \in g^{-1}[U \cap Z]$.

So for any set $O$ open in $Z$ (so we write $O = U \cap Z$ with $U$ is open in $Y$), we know that its inverse image under $g$ is open in $X$ as the inverse image of $U$ under $f$ is open in $X$ by continuity of $f$. So $g$ is continuous.

A bit easier is to note that $i: Z \to Y, \forall x \in Z: i(x) = x$ is continuous when $Z$ has the subspace topology (that topology is defined as the smallest topology that makes $i$ continuous) and that $g = i \circ f$ is continuous as the composition of continuous maps.

Comment: Why $g^{-1}[U \cap Z]=f^{-1}[U] $?

Comment: @Hikicianka see “prooflet”